# What are the implications of creating a table with a composite key of ~6 columns?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I am creating a table that will have a composite key which will comprise of roughly 6 columns. In some queries, I will not be using all 6 columns. Would there be a significant decrease in performance if I create my schema as such?

```
create table my_table (
id int not null,
col_1 char(30),
col_2 char(30),
col_3 char(30),
col_4 int(11),
col_5 int(11),
col_6 char(30),
CONSTRAINT constraint_name PRIMARY KEY (col_1,col_2,col_3,col_4,col_5,col_6)
);

// Example query that doesn't use all the columns
select * from my_table where col_1="hello" and col_2="world";
```

Answer (score 1):

The only significant impact is that the index will take up more space on disk and in memory.

A query that uses all the columns in a prefix of the key will be able to take advantage of the index. So a query that uses `col_1` and `col_2` will be indexed fully (the index is implemented as a B-tree or some similar structure). But a query that uses `col_1` and `col_3` will only use the index to find `col_1`, but will then have to scan all those rows sequentially to test `col_3`.

Comment: I see, is it normal to have a composite key comprising of this many columns? Most of the examples I have seen only have 2-3 columns in their composite key.

Comment: No, it's not very common. But if this is the only unique combination in your application, then it's what you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

If the primary key is needed for integrity, then that's what you need.  If you must have the combinations of the 6 columns be unique, then that's why you have a PRIMARY KEY.

Now, that might not be the best key for the queries you'll be executing, but that's OK: You can create more keys.  In your example of "not using all the columns", you can create a different key with just col_1 and col_2 as the components of the key.

Comment: Note that any prefix of a composite key also acts as an index. So there's no need to create an index on `col_1`.